Audio device constantly restarting in Processing 4.3 (using PCH intel audio device & Ubuntu 22.04)
I am trying to use Processing 4.3 to play and analyse music.
Unfortunately, I am not able to play any sound or listen to the microphone for more than 1 second. The program is running but the audio device seems to be stopped after ~ 100 milliseconds.
For example (see below), when I try to listen to the microphone and measure the volume (using an Amplitude object), the program starts by correctly responding to my voice, but then the volume is freezed to a given value.
My code
import processing.sound.*;

AudioIn in;
Amplitude amp;

void setup() {
    in = new AudioIn(this, 0);
    in.start();
    amp = new Amplitude(this);
    amp.input(in);
    
    print(Sound.list(true));
    print("\navailable channels: " + MultiChannel.availableChannels());
    print("\nactive channel: " + MultiChannel.activeChannel() + "\n");    
}      

void draw() { 
  if( frameCount % 10 == 0 ) {
    print("\nVolume: " + amp.analyze());
  }
  
  if( frameCount % 60 == 0 ) {
    print("\n\nTime passed: " + millis() * 0.001);
    Sound.status();
  }
}

The result
Sound library: JavaSound device listing

      id | Device name         | inputs | outputs
     ----+---------------------+--------+--------
       0 | Port PCH [hw:0]     |      0 |    0
       1 | Port VirMIDI [hw:1] |      0 |    0
 I,O   2 | default [default]   |     32 |   32
       3 | PCH [plughw:0,0]    |      0 |    0
       4 | PCH [plughw:0,3]    |      0 |    8
       5 | PCH [plughw:0,7]    |      0 |    8
       6 | PCH [plughw:0,8]    |      0 |    8
       7 | PCH [plughw:0,9]    |      0 |    8
       8 | PCH [plughw:0,10]   |      0 |    8

Port PCH [hw:0] Port VirMIDI [hw:1] default [default] PCH [plughw:0,0] PCH [plughw:0,3] PCH [plughw:0,7] PCH [plughw:0,8] PCH [plughw:0,9] PCH [plughw:0,10]
available channels: 32
active channel: 0

Volume: 0.0
Volume: 0.015411826
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937

Time passed: 2.209
Sound library: synthesis has been running for 0,11 seconds, generated 4928 frames (framerate 44100)
  audio devices used by JavaSound:
    input from 'default [default]': 32 channels, latency 100ms
    output on 'default [default]': 32 channels, latency 40ms

  nodes in synthesizer network: 2
  decoded audio samples held in cache: 0 (0 frames total)
  CPU usage: 77%


Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937
Volume: 0.013633937

Time passed: 3.21
Sound library: synthesis has been running for 0,11 seconds, generated 4928 frames (framerate 44100)
  audio devices used by JavaSound:
    input from 'default [default]': 32 channels, latency 100ms
    output on 'default [default]': 32 channels, latency 40ms

  nodes in synthesizer network: 2
  decoded audio samples held in cache: 0 (0 frames total)
  CPU usage: 77%

[...]

My configuration
Java 17.0.8
Processing 4.3, with Sound library 2.4.0
Linux 22.04
My audio devices :
aplay -l
**** Liste des périphériques matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0 : ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques : 0/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 3 : HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 7 : HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 8 : HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 9 : HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 10 : HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0


With another audio device
I tried selecting another audio device using "Sound.outputDevice(4);" in setup(). Then, I can successfully analyse my voice, and the audio device does not seem to restart. However, I can't hear any audio sample using this method. I think this alternative method routes the audio stream to an unconnected output (HDMI, probably).

Question was tagged [tag:java], so I was expecting a Java program.

The first tag I have put was processing. Either it has disappeared or I've missed it, sorry. I put it back.

My fault - I didn't know "processing" is a language.  Now I've learnt that, I've improved the tag guidance to make it clearer to other editors.

It could be a permissions problem.  I was getting all zeros for output on MacOS until I did two things:  I reset microphone permissions with Terminal and then launched a newer version of Processing IDE (4.3).  When I did that it asked me if I wanted to allow access to the microphone which I granted.  Then I started seeing values other than zero in the output.

I tested the code that you posted on a System 76 Linux system with Pop!OS and it appeared to run without error.  Console print statements showed non-zero volume numbers persistently from a USB microphone.
